# In Tinymce editor, how to set default font family style in select list?

Tags: wysiwyg

I have [TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/) editor configured and under font family select list, I am able to see 'styles' label as default when loading. But I want to see any font family as default. Suppose, Times new roman as default in select list.

Comment: Any updates on this?

Comment: are u using it via library?

Comment: yes @ monymirza

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [execCommand](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3%3amethod.tinymce.execCommand) to make that work.

> Executes a specific command on the currently active editor.

Try this.

```
editor.execCommand("fontName", false, "Arial");
```

Another way is to use the `content_css` configuration option and name an own css file where you can overwrite the editors defaults (the content.css you were recently looking for). In your init function use something like

```
content_css: "http://sitename/css/my_tiny_styles.css",
```

and in my_tiny_styles.css or whatever file you choose you use

```
font-family: myfont1, myfont2, sans-serif;
```

Answer (score 0):

In the init_instance_callback from http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration3x:init_instance_callback it says:

```
function myCustomInitInstance(inst) {
        alert("Editor: " + inst.editorId + " is now initialized.");
}

tinyMCE.init({
        ...
        init_instance_callback : "myCustomInitInstance"
});
```

but if you try to just enqueue some javascript with those functions Drupal, you can't access tinyMCE since the tinyMCEs are not initialized yet.

Original code I figured out how to reference here, but I extended it.

http://www.group42.ca/adding_and_controlling_tinymce_fonts_in_drupal

You have to create your own function and tap into hook_wysiwyg_editor_settings_alter.

```
 /**
     * Implements hook_wysiwyg_editor_settings_alter().
     * adding custom font in there and setting default size
     */
    function mymodule_wysiwyg_editor_settings_alter(&$settings, $context) {
      if ($context['profile']->editor == 'tinymce') {
        // you can change your font styles there
        $font_styles = array(
          "Calibri=calibri",
          "Comic Sans MS=comic sans ms,sans-serif",
          "Tahoma=tahoma,arial,helvetica,sans-serif",
          "Times New Roman=times new roman,times",
        );

        $settings['theme_advanced_fonts'] = implode(';', $font_styles);
        $settings['theme_advanced_font_sizes'] = "8pt,9pt,10pt,11pt,12pt";

        // this function LangTinyMCEInitialized should be defined in your enqueued javascript file
        $settings['init_instance_callback'] = 'LangTinyMCEInitialized';
      }
    }
```

You also need to have a javascript file containing the **init_instance_callback** callback that is enqueued when the page loads.  The two execCommand calls set up the font and size respectively.

```
//initialize default options in instance callback 
function LangTinyMCEInitialized(ed) {  
  console.log("Editor: " + ed.editorId + " is now initialized.");
  try{
    ed.execCommand("fontName", false, "Calibri");    
    ed.execCommand("fontSize", false, "11pt");    
  }
  catch(err){      
  }
}
```